# Doing math with strings?

Tags: c, string, pointer-arithmetic

I am just browsing through some random code on the net and I stumbled upon this:

```
char *s = "This is a waterfall";
char *search = strstr(s, "Waterfall");

if(search)
{
    temp = malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, s);


    // Substracting to strings?
    len = search - s;
    s[len] = '\0';

    strcat(s, "Rainbow");

    len += strlen(search);

    // What is + len doing here?
    strcat(s, temp + len);

    free(temp);
}
```

I don't get the parts I commented. Would someone please explain?

Comment: I believe you mean `char *search = strstr(s, "Waterfall");`

Comment: Did you mean `strstr(s, "Waterfall")`?  (It'll never match either way, since `s` doesn't contain `"Waterfall"` either...with comparisons being case-sensitive and all.)

Comment: This is called [pointer arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#C_and_C.2B.2B)

Comment: `temp` is not a string. It's a pointer (a memory address). It's not a string (array of characters) until you dereference it to get to the contents (`*temp`).

Comment: Actually, `temp` was not even defined in OP (neither was len).  Can only be deduced it is a pointer from context.

Comment: As written, will not compile.  Need to define both temp and len (`char *temp;`, and `int len;`).  Even then, it will not get past `if(search)` because `strstr()` will look for "Waterfall" in "s", and return NULL into `search`. (Waterfall is not a substring of s).  @Hogan's comments explain what _would_ happen if search was not NULL.

Comment: @Hogan -  Corrections to OP _in an answer or a comment_ are just fine (you have done so in both), But, It does not help to edit out the central issues of the OP _in the OP itself_.  This makes it difficult for future viewers to see the original problem and how it was addressed in the answers.  (referring specifically to `char *search = strstr("s", "Waterfall");`)  (+1 for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @ryyker - look at the history -- all I did was add a tag.  The OP made the edit you speak of.

Answer (score 3):

Many fine comments

```
// string s
char *s = "This is a waterfall";
// string search points to first "waterfall sub-string (nb changed to lowercase to work)
char *search = strstr(s, "waterfall");

// if we found something in search
if(search)
{
    // allocate a space the size of the string s
    temp = malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
    // make a copy of s
    strcpy(temp, s);

    // len now the number of characters between start of string s and search location
    len = search - s;
    // make that location null... (cut the string at that location)
    s[len] = '\0';

    // add rainbow to the end of the string
    strcat(s, "Rainbow");

    // increase the size of len by the size of search result
    len += strlen(search);

    // concatinate to the end of s the data in our copy at the 
    //   location of the size of the search return 
    // BUG : IF you want to concatenate search's original value 
    //       this is not the code which would be needed.
    strcat(s, temp + len);

    // free memory on temp
    free(temp);
}

// BUG! we never allocate additional memory for s even tho s can gets bigger
```

---

## NOTE

I believe if you replace

```
    len += strlen(search);
    strcat(s, temp + len);
```

with

```
    strcat(s, temp + len);
```

You will get the result you want (add the original string searched for to the end of the result.)

You will still have a buffer overflow bug which depending on the compiler will throw an exception or panic or corrupt other string constants.

Answer (score 2):

That's pointer arithmetic, not "math with strings".

s, search, and temp are pointers. Pointers are addresses in memory; they're integers.

s is the address of an array of characters (a "string") in memory. search is intended to be the address of the first character in "Waterfall". That's the eleventh character in that array (though it won't be in practice, because strstr() is not case-blind: The string you're searching for, "waterfall" with a lower-case 'w', is not found in the string you are searching).

So if you subtract s from search, you get the difference between the two addresses: 10.

Similarly, temp is a pointer to a copy of s. If you add len to temp, you get a pointer to the eleventh character from temp. Since temp is a copy of s, that character is intended to be the 'w' in "waterfall". It's trying to copy "Rainbow" over "Waterfall" in the copy of the original string.

But it'll break, because strstr() is sensitive to case.